# Laravel 5.6 - Vue.js installing third party UI Kit and fonts

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.6, getuikit

I am trying to install Now-UI-Kit in Laravel 5.6 with vue.js implementation but not having any success.

URL to Now-UI-Kit: https://demos.creative-tim.com/now-ui-kit/index.html

I was able to install the plain UI Kit by following some very simple steps documented here:
UI Kit Here: https://getuikit.com/

Laravel Steps:  https://github.com/kawax/laravel-uikit

But I couldn't do similar steps for the now-ui-kit.
Both UI KIt and Now-UI-KIt are installed with NPM in node_modules.

Can someone please guide?

Comment: Why are you combining Bootstrap with getuikit? those are 2 different frameworks ..

Comment: I am not.  I am trying to use something other than bootstrap.

Comment: ok but Now-UI-Kit is based on BS4.0

Comment: Yes - but I need to integrate their CSS.

Comment: so why do you need GetUIKit ??

Comment: that was an example that GetUIKIt works but the other one doesn't and I was looking for way to do it.  I don't need GetUIKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright - turned out to be a simple task.  Put all the css files in a sub directory under your assets folder and point to them in app.scss.  laravel-mix will take care of them automatically.